# Relative Paths in Content Editor Web Part

Tags: web-part, html, content-editor-web-part

I have a relatively complex html-structure in a document library, which I want to display in a web part. The web part refers to `site.com/library/index.htm`, from which other pages are called.

Problems occur with the relative paths. `site.com/library/index.htm` is calling `<a href="page1.htm">Page 1</a>` which results into `site.com/library/page1.htm`. But the index.htm within webpart just calls `site.com/page1.htm`.

Is there any way to change this behaviour without adding `../library/` to every single link? Editing every link in a couple of dozen files does not look like an appealing solution. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no other way than updating all the `htm` files. In SharePoint relative paths does not work that way, even if `index.htm` resides inside the Library.. `href='page1.html'` would simply mean `rootsite/page1.htm`

Not even the inner site collection will be placed, that means if you have `rootsite/sites/innersite/library/page1.htm` and you refer it as `href='page1.htm'`, this would simply mean `rootsite/page1.htm`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the BASE tag

```
<head>
  <base href="[url]">
</head>
```

- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag

Comment: That would help very much, but it does not seem to work for me. I couldn't even create a minimal working example. Is <base> supported by SharePoint?

Comment: It is HTML and supported by all Browsers. I *think* the issue is you need to specificy this in the HEAD, so it won't help you when putting the code in a WebPart. I have never used it in combo with SharePoint.

Comment: Hm, seems like I misunderstand something. I created a html and displayed this html with the Content Editor -> not working. If I display this html with the Page Viewer WebPart, everything works fine.
Do I use the Content Editor WebPart in the wrong way? I mostly just display html-files with the Content Editor.

Comment: Do you put the content **in** the CEWP or do you specifiy a link to the file. The last one is way more flexible as you can open the file in any IDE

Comment: I have a `content.html` and the CEWP is just linking to this `content.html`. I do not modify the html-markup inside the CEWP. However the PVWP is working fine for me, I was just not aware that PVWP behaves differently than CEWP.